# Compile and reuse exe in Azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

In Azure DevOps, can I build a solution using the Visual studio Build task, publish the .exe file to the artifacts (or somewhere else, repo?) and then utilize that .exe file in another pipeline?
If so, to where and how should I publish it and then how do I reference it?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D.J. recommended possible solution, though I am using different approach with Universal Packages:

1. Once the binary is produced, the pipeline publishes it as Universal
   Package to Artifact Feet
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#publish-a-universal-package
2. Any other pipeline in project or organization can reference the       Artifact Feed and utilize
   the binary as part of the job
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#download-a-universal-package

This solution requires more effort, since you have to create the Artifact Feed, but it is possible to use the published artifacts across projects within the organization. This is ideal when project produces libraries for integration. Other projects can reference the feed and use up-to-date libraries as part of their build.

Artifact feeds support Semantic Versioning. You can find more about Artifact Feeds in Azure DevOps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/feeds?view=azure-devops

It only depends on what are your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You can use pipeline-artifacts for a start. The artifacts will be associated with the pipline, you'll have a task for publishing at the end of the pipeline that creates the exe-file and downloading at the start of the other pipeline that re-uses that exe.

See this for reference -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic